# How will I combine or differentiate the two yml files for GitLab ci cd yaml script file?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

I've the GitLab ci/cd yaml file script

```
services:
  - docker:19.03.11-dind
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "developer" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "stage"|| ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ (/^([A-Z]([0-9][-_])?)?SPRINT(([-_][A-Z][0-9])?)+/i))
      when: always
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "developer" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "stage"|| ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ (/^([A-Z]([0-9][-_])?)?SPRINT(([-_][A-Z][0-9])?)+/i))
      when: never 
stages:
  - build
  - Publish
  - deploy
cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository
    - target
build_jar:
  image: maven:3.8.3-jdk-11
  stage: build
  script: 
    - mvn clean install package -DskipTests=true
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar
docker_build:
  stage: Publish
  image: docker:19.03.11
  services:
    - docker:19.03.11-dind
  variables:
    IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
  script: 
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG .
    - docker push $IMAGE_TAG
deploy_dev:
  stage: deploy
  image: stellacenter/aws-helm-kubectl
  before_script:
    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id ${DEV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key ${DEV_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
    - aws configure set region ${DEV_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
  script:
    - sed -i "s/<VERSION>/${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}/g" provider-service-dev.yml    
    - mkdir -p  $HOME/.kube
    - cp $KUBE_CONFIG_DEV $HOME/.kube/config
    - chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config 
    - export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config
    - kubectl apply -f provider-service-dev.yml
  only:
    - developer 
deploy_stage:
  stage: deploy
  image: stellacenter/aws-helm-kubectl
  before_script:
    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id ${DEV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key ${DEV_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
    - aws configure set region ${DEV_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
  script:
    - sed -i "s/<VERSION>/${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}/g" provider-service-stage.yml    
    - mkdir -p  $HOME/.kube
    - cp $KUBE_CONFIG_STAGE $HOME/.kube/config
    - chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config 
    - export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config
    - kubectl apply -f provider-service-stage.yml
  only:
    - stage
```

this yaml script which I combine into two branches i.e developer and stage
but I'm having two yml files for separate branches (for developer and stage)

provider-service-dev.yml

```
   apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: provider-app
  namespace: stellacenter-dev
  labels:
    app: provider-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app : provider-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: provider-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: provider-app
        image: registry.gitlab.com/stella-center/backend-services/provider-service:<VERSION>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8092
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name:  gitlab-registry-token-auth

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name:  provider-service
  namespace: stellacenter-dev
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app:  provider-app
  ports:
  - port:  8092
    targetPort:  8092
```

provider-service-stage.yml

```
   apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: provider-app
  namespace: stellacenter-stage-uat
  labels:
    app: provider-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app : provider-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: provider-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: provider-app
        image: registry.gitlab.com/stella-center/backend-services/provider-service:<VERSION>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8092
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name:  gitlab-registry-token-auth

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name:  provider-service
  namespace: stellacenter-stage-uat
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app:  provider-app
  ports:
  - port:  8092
    targetPort:  8092
```

I have separately mentioned in the gitlab cicd yaml script but it shows the error like

```
$ kubectl apply -f provider-service-dev.yml
Error from server (NotFound): error when creating "provider-service-dev.yml": namespaces "stellacenter-dev" not found
Error from server (NotFound): error when creating "provider-service-dev.yml": namespaces "stellacenter-dev" not found
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

It shows error in the last line of the script. It shows that the namespaces can't found but that was there only . I don't know how to sort it out this. Please Kindly help me to sort it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your issue properly you can do it by editing this **stage** and add **one** **variable** : CI_COMMIT_BRANCH

Docker build command will be something like : `docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG -f $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH .`

```
docker_build:
  stage: Publish
  image: docker:19.03.11
  services:
    - docker:19.03.11-dind
  variables:
    IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
  script: 
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG -f $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH .
    - docker push $IMAGE_TAG
```

So now you have to keep both docker files in the repo however just change the name of those files as per the **branch** name.

```
developer:
    FROM maven:3.8.3-jdk-11 AS MAVEN_BUILD
    COPY pom.xml /build/
    COPY src /build/src/
    WORKDIR /build/
    RUN mvn clean install package -DskipTests=true
    FROM openjdk:11
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/target/provider-service-*.jar /app/provider-service.jar
    ENV PORT 8092
    EXPOSE $PORT
    ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=development","-jar","/app/provider-service.jar"]
```

and

```
stage:
    FROM maven:3.8.3-jdk-11 AS MAVEN_BUILD
    COPY pom.xml /build/
    COPY src /build/src/
    WORKDIR /build/
    RUN mvn clean install package -DskipTests=true
    FROM openjdk:11
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/target/provider-service-*.jar /app/provider-service.jar
    ENV PORT 8092
    EXPOSE $PORT
    ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=stage","-jar","/app/provider-service.jar"]
```

Comment: How will it works ? for updating  {docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG -f $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH} The CI_COMMIT_BRANCH variable is for commit pipeline or else Can you get me clear about the variable to add? then the requirement was , we have two docker file, If I go with developer branch ,pipeline runs, it will automatically redirected to the developer-dockerfile as same as stage or else like we combine the yaml script likely can we combine docker file?

Comment: so when pipeline will work branch name will be `dev` so variable will set docker file name in command as `dev` and docker will start building the image. `-f` you are passing the name of docker file to command. You have to save your dockerfile with name `dev` into repo and path you can give into command with `-f`, so docker file names will be similar to branch name as simple as that. On any branch CI/CD will run, default variable will be there I think `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH`, your docker build command will get the filename using that variable and find a file in repo with name for build instruction.

Comment: I changed as the docker files as stage.Dockerfile

Comment: that depends on you what you want to keep the name of Dockfile and accordingly, you can pass the name using variable to docker build command simple as that. Manage that variable using if, else command or use default just branch name.

Comment: yes its working but the pipeline fails for deploy stage. I will edit the content again . Please review it @Harsh Manvan

Comment: You namespace is missing please try creating it.

Answer (score 1):

`rules:variables:` likely fits this use case nicely. You can use `rules:` to change environment variables. Use this to set the location of your dockerfile based on the branch name. Pass this variable to the `-f` flag in `docker build` to make it use that dockerfile.

```yaml
docker_build:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      variables:
        DOCKERFILE_PATH: "Dockerfile"
    - if: '"$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "stage"'
      variables:
        DOCKERFILE_PATH: "staging.Dockerfile"
    # and so on
  script:
    # ...
    - echo "Building dockerfile: ${DOCKERFILE_PATH}"
    - docker build -t registry.tld/myimage:latest -f "$DOCKERFILE_PATH" .
```